# How to I prevent System.Xaml.XamlXmlWriter from escaping my MarkupExtension?

Tags: c#, xaml, c#-4.0

I'm using the XamlServices.Transform to take an object model and serialize it to Xaml.

I've implemented a class which inherits from XamlXmlWriter which overrides WriteValue. I'm using this to reinstantiate a custom MarkupExtension back into the rendered Xaml.

When I replace the "value" in WriteValue with a the syntax for the MarkupExtension the XamlXmlWriter escapes the MarkupExtension for me automatically.

So say I set the value to "{MyExtension}" the rendered xaml looks like this "{}{MyExtension}" - I want the unescaped former version.

Currently I'm doing a nasty Replace("=\"{}{MyExtension","{MyExtension}") on the xaml after it's been created, which works but isn't pretty.

Is there a way to intercept the writing of the Xaml at the point this escaping goes on and tell it not to escape the MarkUpExtension? Or perhaps there's a better way to render the MarkUpExtension?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know you can add a `TypeConverterAttribute` to the property (or the type itself) that converts it to a `MarkupExtension`. So if `MyClass` should be serialized using MyExtension, use (untested, from memory, probably has typos):

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassToMyExtensionConverter))]
public sealed class MyClass { }

public sealed class MyExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) { return new MyClass(); }
}

public sealed class MyClassToMyExtensionConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext ctx, Type t) { return t == typeof(MarkupExtension); }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext ctx, CultureInfo culture, object obj, Type t) { return ConvertToInternal((MyClass) obj); }
    private MyExtension ConvertToInternal(MyClass value) { return new MyExtension(); }
}
```

Is this what you're looking for, or do you need to be able to do it within the XamlXmlWriter?

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the information. No it doesn't help in my situation. I need it from the XamlxmlWriter itself. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @Daniel James Bryars -- Oops; sorry it took so long to get back. Can you implement your own XamlSchemaContext?